# Azure AD : Accessing UserManager<IdentityUser>

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

In previous projects, I have used ASP Identity to manage user management.

I have used

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager and RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>();
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddTokenProvider<TestTokenProvider<AppUser>>("Test");
```

In my latest project, I am using Active Directory to manage users (App Registration, Roles etc)

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
   .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
   .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

What I am trying to work out is how do I access the details of the current logged-in user.  For example what roles it has etc.  Can this still be used by UserManager or do I have to go via the GraphApi?

Comment: Can you share the documentation that you're following to set this all up so I can gain a better understanding of your issue?

You should also be able to get the current logged-in user info using the Graph API. For [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161611/getting-user-details-from-azure-ad-in-asp-net).